# required percentage of column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three column a,b,c I want to fill true or false in the 'c' column if the value of 'b' column under or above 10% of 'a' column ............
actually, I want to update column 'b' if the value nearest column a

```
a   |  b   |  c
100 | 90   | true
100 | 110  | true
100 | 88   | false
```

I want to generate a query in PostgreSQL

Comment: I don't get it... 90 and 88 both are above 10% of 100, so why one have true and another false?

Comment: @Oto Shavadze: A language problem, obviously. This is probably about `a` +/- 10%.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - If so,  then clear.

Comment: @user2638158: You see this is a bit confusing. Can you please add the desired result, so we see what `b` values you expect?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this  :

```
SELECT a, b, CASE WHEN ABS(a-b) <=0.1*a THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS c
FROM yourtable;
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
1   100 90  True
2   100 110 True
3   100 88  False
```

About updating b, you didn't specify which value you want to use for b, but you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET b = <your value>
WHERE ABS(a-b) <=0.1*a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to know whether

```
b between a * 0.9 and a * 1.1
```

When this is not the case (or so I understand it) you want b to be set to `a * 0.9` or `a * 1.1`:

```
update mytable
set b = case when b < a then a * 0.9 else a * 1.1 end
where b not between a * 0.9 and a * 1.1;
```

(These formulas only work for positive values. You'd have to adjust them, if your table also contains negative values.)